# What type of List i should take to Join (Inner) 2 tables from an another table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have 3 tables **User, Product and Orders**.

```
USER:
-----+-----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
 u_id | username  | password   | contact | email   | city      |
------+-----------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+

PRODUCT:
+------+----------+--------------+------+--------------+
| p_id | category | listed_price | qty  | description  |
+------+----------+--------------+------+--------------+

ORDERS:
+------+--------+------+------+-----------+
| o_id | date   | u_id | p_Id | order_qty |
+------+--------+------+------+-----------+
```

I wants to Inner joins User table with Product along with o_id (from ORDER) in below order:

```
+-----------+-------+------+------+--------------+
| username  | email | p_id | o_id | listed_price |
+-----------+-------+------+------+--------------+
```

My SQL Query is below :

```
productList = (List<Object[]>) session.createSQLQuery(
    "SELECT User.username, User.email, Orders.p_id, Orders.o_id, Product.listed_price " +
    "FROM Orders " +
    "INNER JOIN User " +
    "ON User.u_id = Orders.u_id" +
    "INNER JOIN Product " +
    "ON Product.p_id = Orders.p_id " +
    "WHERE Product.p_id = '"+p_id +"' " +
    "ORDER BY User.username").list();
```

Comment: Your query style is open to a big security flaw.  Don't ever build SQL strings with parameters like that, google "SQL Injection" and save yourself a lot of pain and your employer a lot of professional indemnity insurance..

Answer (score 0):

It will return `List<Object[]>`. (list of object array), where each array represents a row in result. And index of values are based on your select statement.

Here you are selecting following things:

```
User.username, User.email, Orders.p_id, Orders.o_id, Product.listed_price
```

So you will get 5 elements in each object array. Where 1st element will be username, 2nd will be email, and so on...

Comment: Unable to get output on JSP page. I'm using same List in JSP page for iterating vales but unable to get data on jsp page. Infact not getting any error after debugging.

Comment: @DevSingh this can be due to multiple issue. Without looking at your code its hard to guess whats the problem is.

Comment: Please see code snippets below link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089460/unable-to-get-result-after-inner-join-3-tables

Answer (score 0):

From your query `"SELECT User.username, User.email, Orders.p_id, Orders.o_id, Product.listed_price"` it will return  `List<Object[]>`.