# Unable to get result after Inner Join 3 tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I have declare a `List<Object[]>` which returning list of object array, where each array represents a row in result. And index of values are based on your select statement.

```
productList = 
(List<Object[]>) session.createSQLQuery("
SELECT User.username, User.email, Orders.p_id, Orders.o_id, Product.listed_price " +                                                                                         
"FROM Orders " +                                                                     
"INNER JOIN User ON User.u_id = Orders.u_id " +                                                                  
"INNER JOIN Product ON Product.p_id = Orders.p_id " +                                                                
"WHERE Product.p_id = '"+p_id +"' " +                                                            
"ORDER BY User.username").list();
```

I have 3 tables **User, Product and Orders**.

```
USER:
-----+-----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
 u_id | username  | password   | contact | email   | city      |
------+-----------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+

PRODUCT:
+------+----------+--------------+------+--------------+
| p_id | category | listed_price | qty  | description  |
+------+----------+--------------+------+--------------+

ORDERS:
+------+--------+------+------+-----------+
| o_id | date   | u_id | p_Id | order_qty |
+------+--------+------+------+-----------+
```

I wants to Inner joins User table with Product along with o_id (from ORDER) in below order:

```
+-----------+-------+------+------+--------------+
| username  | email | p_id | o_id | listed_price |
+-----------+-------+------+------+--------------+
```

In my ActionClass/View class i declare `public List<Object[]> productList;` to access object list from controller class above.

```
public List<Object[]> productList;

public String listAllProduct(){
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
        productList = orderDaoFactory.listProduct(Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter("p_id"))); 
         System.out.println("\t"+productList.get(0).toString());
        return SUCCESS;
}
```

In my JSP page i'm using this list (array of object) productList as an Iterator tag to iterate all customers who have ordered that product.

```
<s:iterator value="productList">

        <tr>
            <td><h4><s:property value="username"/></h4></td>    
            <td><h4><s:property value="email"/></h4></td>
            <td><h4><s:property value="p_id"/></h4></td>
            <td><h4><s:property value="o_id"/></h4></td>
            <td><h4><s:property value="listed_price"/></h4></td>            
        </tr>

</s:iterator>
```

**Challenges/Issues:** My problem is not to get output successfully even not getting any error after debugging. Empty mind now thinking to use O/R mapping to associate Objects JOIN with others. Please suggest me where i am wrong. Your suggestions appreciable.

Comment: What's the question?  What problem are you seeing?

Comment: Unable to view data/result on JSP page. Don't know whatever i need O/R mapping because all 3 tables are having POJO.

Answer (score 0):

```
productList = 
(List<Object[]>) session.createSQLQuery("
SELECT User, Orders, Product" +                                                                                         
"FROM User,Orders,Product " +                                                                     
"INNER JOIN User ON User.u_id = Orders.u_id " +                                                                  
"INNER JOIN Product ON Product.p_id = Orders.p_id " +                                                                
"WHERE Product.p_id = '"+p_id +"' " +                                                            
"ORDER BY User.username").list();
Then you will get three object. In first list you will get Object[0]=Users,Object[1]=Orders,Object[2]=Product. Now iterate it.
```

after edition

```
productList = 
(List<Object[]>) session.createQuery("
SELECT User, Orders, Product" +                                                                                         
"FROM User,Orders,Product " +                                                                     
"INNER JOIN User ON User.u_id = Orders.u_id " +                                                                  
"INNER JOIN Product ON Product.p_id = Orders.p_id " +                                                                
"WHERE Product.p_id = '"+p_id +"' " +                                                            
"ORDER BY User.username").list();
```

what is the problem with is syntax??

Comment: How can you SELECT <TableName> instead of <ColumnName>. Is it right ?

Comment: User, Product and Orders are Pojo classes. But here i'm using native SQL query in hibernate So, createSQLquery() method i have used. I may go wrong So please suggest me.

Comment: createQuery() method in HQL doesn't support ON clause. So here i was using createSQLquery().

Answer (score 0):

Use HQL instead of SQL if you want to query your objects directly. Use `session.createQuery(String)` with the following query :

```
SELECT u.username, u.email, o.p_id, o.o_id, p.listed_price FROM Orders as o
INNER JOIN User as u WITH u.u_id = o.u_id
INNER JOIN Product as p WITH p.p_id = o.p_id
WHERE p.p_id = ???
ORDER BY u.username
```

Comment: I am getting QuerySyntaxError: unexpected token.

Comment: it seems you are missing a space before your first INNER JOIN

Comment: I have checked spaces everywhere. It's showing unexpected token: WITH near line 1, column 124. Seems WITH clause is not used in HQL.

Comment: which Hibernate version do you use ? You might have to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: Hibernate 3.0. But i don't think Hibernate version problem here.

Comment: This version of Hibernate does not support the with-clause. Please upgrade to a more recent version 3.6 or even 4.X

Comment: Will you please suggest me with 3.o version so i can carry on my task.

Comment: If you don't have any restrictions you should take the latest released version, that is to say 4.1.9.Final

Comment: Then take the highest release that matches your restrictions, here is a list http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core